# Has there been work done where we consider the limit of a function to be another function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Has there been work done on functions whose limit is also a function? I am specifically referring to limits as x approaches infinity. The idea is that we are expanding the definition of a limit to include non-constants, kind of looking at end-behavior in more detail. Instead of just saying a function approaches infinity, we might say that it approaches infinity in the way the $f(x)=x^3$ approaches infinity.

A definition might look like this:

> $lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=g(x)$ when $lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)-g(x)]=0$

This seems to me to be a natural extension of the current definition that takes the statement

$lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=c$

to mean that $f(x)$ approaches the constant function $g(x)=c$.

That is, f behaves like g(x)=c.

Comment: The first statement does not make sense, since the left hand side ($\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) $) does not depend on $x$ while $g(x)$ does.

Comment: That's kind of the idea. I want to expand the definition of a limit to something that could depend on x as opposed to requiring it to be a constant.

Comment: You might be thinking of the idea of an Asymptotic formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_formula  where one function tends to another function for very large inputs, or more formally where $\lim_{x\to \infty} f / g = 1$

Comment: there is the notion of a family of functions, like $f(x,y)$. In this case it makes sense to ask whether $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x,y) = g(y)$ and then to study the properties of such $g$.